# alerts according to 'if' statement

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Depending on the value of the variable `name` I need to show an alert, If it is empty it must show me an alert and if they contain value it must show me another different alert, my code that I am using is the following:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var name = ""

    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var showAlertok = false

    var alert: Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("it is empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) )
    }

    var alertok: Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text("It's not empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")) {
            // here action
            print("OK button tapped")

            })
    }



    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Title")

            Button(action: {

                if self.name.isEmpty {
                    print("it is empty")
                    self.showAlert.toggle()


                } else {

                    print("It's not empty")
                    self.showAlertok.toggle()

                }


            }) {

                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                    Text("SEND")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)

            }   .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: { self.alert })
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlertok, content: { self.alertok })
        }
    }
}
```

In the previous code if `name` is empty, the alert does not work, it only shows me the value of `print("it is empty")` on the console. If the value of `name` contains a value, the alert is displayed.

Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess when you code like that SwiftUI accept the last one and you can see "Not empty alert". But if you write just one ".alert" block u can achieve to see your alerts both. Here is my solution.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var name = ""
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var alert: Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("it is empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) )
    }

    var alertok: Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text("It's not empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")) {
            // here action
            print("OK button tapped")

            })
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Title")

            Button(action: {

                self.showAlert.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                    Text("SEND")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: { name.isEmpty ? self.alert : self.alertok })
        }
    }
}
```